# how to set regex for full name in spry framework

Tags: javascript, regex, spry

I want to change below php regex for java script regex to use them in spry validation framework.
1)`"/^[\d]+$/"`
2)`"/^([\x{600}-\x{6FF}]+\s)*[\x{600}-\x{6FF}]+$/u"`
3)`"/^([\x{600}-\x{6FF}]+\d*\s)*[\x{600}-\x{6FF}]+\d*$/u"`
I don't know difference between php format and javascript format in above regexs.

Answer (score 0):

Regex patterns in PHP are enclosed in quotations AND delimiters such as `//` or `@@`. In javascript, regex patterns don't need to be enclosed in strings.

If that's not the problem, then you need to post more code for us to help.

In **PHP:**

```
preg_match('/hello/','hello world');
```

In **javascript:**

```
'hello world'.match(/hello/);
```

Comment: i want to check full name in spry framework but i can't use above pattern. with above format spry doesn't allow to use type his/her full name.
i want to use persian unicode for fullname. persian unicode is [\u0600-\u06FF]

Comment: @fireboy - So are you saying the problem is the Persian Unicode stuff? Or JavaScript format versus PHP format regexes?

Comment: my problem is JavaScript format vs PHP format regex. i can't use /^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$/ in spry framework.